# NRefactory Resolve Attribute

Tags: c#, nrefactory

I would like to resolve the attributes that are associated to methods in a class using NRefactory.

I create a syntax tree from a cs file. Then I go on to find the only type that I have in the file. Then I find the methods that are associated to the file.

```
var parser = new ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.CSharpParser();
SyntaxTree tree = parser.Parse(line, "demo.cs");        
...
CSharpUnresolvedFile file = tree.ToTypeSystem();

foreach (IUnresolvedTypeDefinition type in file.TopLevelTypeDefinitions)
{
    foreach (IUnresolvedMethod method in type.Methods)
    {
    }
}
```

I know that IUnresolvedMethod has a property called "Attributes" which is of type IList.

The archive that I am parsing looks like this:

```
namespace DynamicsFieldsSite.Controllers.FundRaising
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Controlador API de Acciones de Cuenta
    /// </summary>
    public class AccountActionsApiController : ApiController
    {
        private const string fullControllerPath = "api/FundRaising/AccountActionsApi";
        private const string actionKeyPath = "AccountActionsApi";

        private AccountActionManagement _accountActionManage;
        private SystemAppComponent _systemAppComp;

        /// <summary>
        /// Inicializa una nueva instancia de la clase <see cref="AccountActionsApiController" />.
        /// </summary>
        public AccountActionsApiController()
        {
            _accountActionManage = new AccountActionManagement(this.GenerateInformation());
            _systemAppComp = new SystemAppComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene un listado de modelos vista item de Acciones de Cuenta.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Listado de modelos vista item de Acciones de Cuenta.</returns>
        [WebApiAuthorize(ActionKey = actionKeyPath + "-01")]
        [Route(fullControllerPath + "/Get")]
        public List<AccountActionItemViewModel> GetAllAccountActions()
        {
            return _accountActionManage.GetAllAccountActions();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to resolve the attributes so I could get the string within the attribute tags. (Ex. fullControllerPath + "/Get"). I have looked around but I have not find help to get me started. I came across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840420/nrefactory-how-do-i-access-unresolved-named-arguments-on-a-property-attribute) in which the OP managed to solve the syntax tree but it did not become clear to me how what he did could relate to what I want to do. Thanks for your share of expertise on this one.